# REtrieveing the atest record in oracle using rank/ group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, rank

I have the following Query which is giving me the results i have attached with this post. I want to bring only the records where most recent status is updated. Please note that there is no date column to identify the updated status. The only way we can so it is group by (IDK,IDFK,STATUS). Please note that one CODE can be updated number of times. I want to get the most latest status updated (so basically for every code for every status update the max IDFK) . so from the below screen shots i should get three records (i.e. wehre IDFK is 1418853,1418939,1419017)

NOTE: IDK and IDFK may/may not be in sorted order.

```
    SELECT ID.ISS_CD CODE,
         IF.ISS_DIM_KY IDK,
         IF.LOAD_TS,
         IE.ISS_FACT_DIM_KY IFDK,
         IE.SUSPN_STS
 FROM ccm_mi_rds_owner.iss_fact if
         INNER JOIN ccm_mi_rds_owner.iss_dim id ON (IF.ISS_DIM_KY = ID.ISS_DIM_KY)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ccm_mi_rds_owner.iss_fact_ext ie ON (IF.ISS_FACT_DIM_KY = IE.ISS_FACT_DIM_KY)
   WHERE IF.SRC_DIM_KY = 20  
   and IE.SUSPN_STS is not null
   and iss_cd in ('C0000182087' , 'C0000182142','C0000182999')``
```

[image: Result of the Query]

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's analytical functions are a good fit for this.
Try the below:

```
select
  *
from
(
    SELECT ID.ISS_CD CODE,
         IF.ISS_DIM_KY IDK,
         IF.LOAD_TS,
         IE.ISS_FACT_DIM_KY IFDK,
         IE.SUSPN_STS,
         row_number() over (partition by idk order by idfk desc ) as rn
 FROM ccm_mi_rds_owner.iss_fact if
         INNER JOIN ccm_mi_rds_owner.iss_dim id ON (IF.ISS_DIM_KY = ID.ISS_DIM_KY)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ccm_mi_rds_owner.iss_fact_ext ie ON (IF.ISS_FACT_DIM_KY = IE.ISS_FACT_DIM_KY)
   WHERE IF.SRC_DIM_KY = 20  
   and IE.SUSPN_STS is not null
   and iss_cd in ('C0000182087' , 'C0000182142','C0000182999')
)
where
  rn = 1
```